# Automatic extraction of recent nine months data in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a data frame which consists of data aggregated over certain time span with 'date'as one of the columns. Now every day a new data with exactly same columns is added to this aggregated data. Now I want to apply a filter on this aggregated data, that post appending new daily data I want only recent nine months data.

Suppose df_old is your aggregated data and new data is df_new. Currently I am doing like this

```
#Append new data to old aggregated data with same columns
df_old=df_old.append(df_new)
df_old['date']=pd.to_datetime(df_old['date'])
max_date=max(df_old['date']
df_old['date_diff']=(max_date - df_old['date'])
##Considering a calender month has 30 days and three months have 31 days
df_old.loc[df_old.date_diff <=273]
```

Now I know the above method involves hard coding and is not efficient. I would appreciate if someone can help with some automated way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically generate 6 months old date

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

six_months_old = date.today() + relativedelta(months=-6)

six_months_old
#datetime.date(2016, 9, 5)
```

now use this value to filter your dataframe

```
df_old = df_old.append(df_new)
df_old['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_old['date'])
max_date = max(df_old['date']

result_df = df_old.loc[(df_old['date'] >= six_months_old)]
```

Comment: Thanks Vikash!!....Thats what I was looking for....I wanted to avoid any hardcoding.

Comment: @user2906657 you are welcome :) Please tick the answer if it matches expectations. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit more "Pandaic" solution:

Data:

```
In [40]: df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2000-01-01', freq='29D', periods=15), columns=['Date'])

In [41]: df
Out[41]:
         Date
0  2000-01-01
1  2000-01-30
2  2000-02-28
3  2000-03-28
4  2000-04-26
5  2000-05-25
6  2000-06-23
7  2000-07-22
8  2000-08-20
9  2000-09-18
10 2000-10-17
11 2000-11-15
12 2000-12-14
13 2001-01-12
14 2001-02-10
```

Solution:

```
In [42]: df.loc[df['Date'] > df['Date'].max() - pd.DateOffset(months=9)]
Out[42]:
         Date
5  2000-05-25
6  2000-06-23
7  2000-07-22
8  2000-08-20
9  2000-09-18
10 2000-10-17
11 2000-11-15
12 2000-12-14
13 2001-01-12
14 2001-02-10
```